# How to prove this specific kernel is not in RKHS?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning

Consider $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}$, and $k(x,y)=xy=[\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}]\cdot [\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}]^T$, where we thus can define two kinds of feature maps $\Phi_1(x)=x$ and $\Phi_2(x)=[\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}]$, and the feature space are respectively $\mathcal{H}_1=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{H}_2=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then a **claim** says that: neither of these two feature space is a  RKHS ( Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space), as they are not spaces of functions on $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}$.

Could anyone help to interpret this **claim**? I still do not know how to prove if they are  in RKHS or not.

Comment: Could you help? @Jihad

Comment: Have you ever used IRC before?

Comment: @crash sorry I did not know IRC, could you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: It's like another math forum but where chatting is okay. It's not frowned upon. Check this out: http://webchat.freenode.net/. Just type in an arbitrary nickname (e.g., babydragon or simply olivia would be fine), the channel (#math), and then connect. My nickname is induktio there. If you connect, I can show you kind of how it works if you want (you may be able to find help there).